# Update files in one GIT repository from those in another

Tags: git, github

It seems there must be an obvious way to do this, but advice appreciated....

I have a large project where I do a lot of the coding (for the back-end app engine) and a team does a lot for the front-end, which includes the interface in the back-end to the engine (like an adapter).

On my machine, I have two parallel GIT structures.  Let's call A the one where I keep developing the engine, and B the latest where they keep working on the other stuff.

What I want to do is (1) create a branch of the remote B repository, which has a quite changed file/directory structure since we diverged a good while ago; (2) take a few files from my local A structure, move them (with their history, of course) into the local B repository (in the right places), and (3) push this branch of B back to the remote for B.

I suspect I can just move/copy files from A to the right place in B, and GIT will think/see a lot of edits took place.  But I think, then, I would lose all the GIT history.

I don't want to lose the A repository - I just want to 'update' the new branch on the B repository to capture all the work I have done along the way, along with its history.

FYI, if it's not obvious, the goal here is for them to be able to look at this new branch, then pull my edits of the last month into the 'develop' branch on the B repository.

Comment: Maybe you can consider cherry-picking commits. Else, you can also checkout files from remotes directly - via git checkout --

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it right, repository "A" and "B" is two branch from the same master.

Create a branch from your "B" repository and checkout this new branch. You can merge "A" repository into this new branch. All history (including the merge) will be there and you can move all files into the correct place (or resolve conflict if you have). Then checkout the "B" branch so you can merge this new branch into it. You can then keep working an "A" and "B" separately.

If you want to cherry-pick only a few files from "A", make sure not to auto-commit the branch when you merge, so you can discard all unwanted changes from the new branch and keep (stage or add) only the cherry-picked files. Once committed, do as mentioned above (checkout back to "B" and merge the new branch into that.) When you are done, you can delete the unwanted branch, so you will have "A" and "B" with all the histories.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do the step 'merge "A" repository into this new branch'?  I will be in a directory structure and Git environment that is tied to the B repository.  I can see how to create the branch, but then how do I tell Git "I am here in B; go get the stuff from the 'A' respository and mege it into this branch"?

Comment: after you checkout new branch, simply: git merge A. Consider using a git UI (both Sourcetree, GitKraken are nice) where you can visually see how branches connect. With sourcetree it's very simple, click on the branch you want to merge, and select: merge "branchname" into the current branch. A good git collaborating guide: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches

Comment: Is Sourcetree only available for Windows and Mac?